# A torsion abelian group is indecomposable if and only if it is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$ for some prime $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I am self-studying group theory and in Exercise 10.38 of Rotman's *An Introduction to the Theory of Groups*, the exercise is to prove that a torsion abelian group is indecomposable if and only if it is isomorphic to a subgroup of the Prüfer group $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$ for some prime $p$. So far I have:

Assume $G$ is indecomposable. Since $G$ is a torsion abelian group, it is the direct product of its $p$-primary components, but as it is indecomposable, it must itself be $p$-primary for some prime $p$. Imbed $G$ in a divisible abelian group $D$. Now the torsion subgroup of $D$, $tD$, is also divisible and contains $G$, and by the classification of divisible abelian groups, $tD$ is isomorphic to a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}(p_i^\infty)$ for various primes $p_i$. But there can be no copies of $\mathbb{Q}$ as $tD$ is torsion, so there are only copies of the $\mathbb{Z}(p_i^\infty)$, and therefore $G \leq tD \cong \sum \mathbb{Z}(p_i^\infty)$ for some primes $p_i$. But since $G$ is $p$-primary, it cannot contain any elements with a nonzero component from any direct summand $A_i$ with $p_i \neq p$, for then that element's order would contain other factors than $p$. Therefore $G \leq \sum_{i \in I} \mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$ for some indexing set $I$.

From here, there must be some way to "reduce" $|I|$ down to $1$, but I don't see how to show $I$ can even be finite. As far as I know, it isn't necessarily the case that $G$ lies in only one "coordinate" of $\sum_{i \in I} \mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$, since there could be an isomorphic copy of $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$ in the sum that is not one of these direct summands, and *that* could be where $G$ lies inside. I have considered using the Ulm invariants, but we have only talked about and proven results for $U\{n, G\}$ with $n$ finite and $G$ a direct sum of cyclic groups. I have also considered writing $G$ as a direct sum of a divisible group and a reduced group, and so by indecomposability it must be either divisible or reduced - if it is divisible, it must be isomorphic to the whole of $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$ and we are done, but in the reduced case, I have not found any use of knowing that $G$ is reduced.

(The converse direction is much more straightforward: subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$ are either cyclic of order $p^n$ or are the whole of $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$. The former case is indecomposable as a consequence of the classification of finite abelian groups, and the latter case is indecomposable since it is infinite and all proper subgroups are finite.)

Comment: $tD$ is the torsion subgroup of $D$ (the subgroup consisting of those elements of finite order).

Comment: Edited - I hadn't realized the notation wasn't standard, Rotman introduces $tG$ for the torsion subgroup of a group $G$.

Comment: On the topic of notation, it might also help to indicate in the question what $\mathbf Z(p^\infty)$ means when it is first used.  Concretely, it's (i) the group of $p$-power roots of unity in $\mathbf C^\times$ or (ii) the subgroup of elements of $p$-power order in $\mathbf Q/\mathbf Z$ or (iii) the group $\mathbf Q_p/\mathbf Z_p$. Also, you could refer people to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Oh dear! I regret to have to inform you that we are now at war with one another!

Comment: I was wondering if it was the Prűfer group. @KCd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $G$ is divisible, then $G$ is a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Z}/(p^\infty)$ and thus isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/(p^\infty)$ by indecomposability.  Otherwise, $G$ must have a cyclic direct summand (by Corollary 10.43 in Rotman) and so must be cyclic by indecomposability.

Comment: Ah perfect, thank you! You've answered two questions of mine now by using this pure cyclic direct summand, I should take a lesson to think of that theorem more when struggling in this section. :P

Comment: Apparently, instead of $\mathbb{Z}/(p^\infty)$, it should be $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$.